# Disable Transaction for specific method

Tags: java, spring

I'm using a Interface with @Transaction, and I have a method that performs a loop and check some information, but this loop takes long time to finish it, and i added a parameter in the database. And inside of the loop, is checked the parameter, and if is equal true, the loop will stop.

My problem is at the moment that check the parameter, it not get the parameter updated, it keep with the old value of the parameter.
is there a way to keep the transaction on interface and disable for specific method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to split in two your method and you put "Requires new" on that check the parameters, in order to create a new transaction and suspend the current transaction if one exists.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is undestand why you are using @Transaction on interfaces, beacause the correct way is to annote concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation.

From spring references documentation:

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact that Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies ( proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect ( mode="aspectj"), then the transaction settings are not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

Then can you share your code with us?